# How to add white gaussian noise to an image in Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I want to add white gaussian noise to an image of 10 dB in Matlab.

I tried to use Matlab function imnoise but I couldn't figure out what values for mean and variance should I choose to add noise of 10 dB.

How do I do this ?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, consider upvoting and/or accepting it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Additive noise is usually mean-free, i.e. the mean should be 0. A noise level of 10 dB = 1 B ("bel") usually means that the variance of the noise is by a factor 10¹ = 10 smaller than the variance of the image. As the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imnoise.html) states, the variance parameter to `imshow` is interpreted under the assumption that the image data are doubles in the range [0, 1].

Here's an example:

Load sample grayscale image included with Matlab:

```
[I, map] = imread('eight.tif');
```

That image is of data type `uint8`, i.e. integers in the range 0 to 255. Let's convert it to a double in [0, 1]:

```
I = double(I) / 255;
```

Compute the image variance

```
v = var(I(:));
```

and tell `imnoise` to add Gaussian white noise with mean 0 and a tenth of that variance:

```
J = imnoise(I, 'gaussian', 0, v / 10);
```

This is the result:

[image]

Because `imnoise` clips the data to the range [0, 1] after adding noise, the actual noise variance is smaller,

```
var(J(:) - I(:)) / v
```

gives something like 0.093.

Answer (score 2):

use y=wgn(m,n,p) command in matlab.
it generates a mxn matrix of white Gaussian noise. p specifies the power of y in decibels relative to a watt.